# How to give unique hyperlink to different day of the month?

Tags: php, date, calendar

i found this script (calendar) on the internet, and i dont know how to give unique hyperlink (a href) to a different day of the month.

Example: if i am clicking on the 14th day, i want that link redirect me to the google.com
Example: if 20th day = yahoo.com

...

```
<?php
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");

$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];

$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;

if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
$prev_month = 12;
$prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}

if ($next_month == 13 ) {
$next_month = 1;
$next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>">Previous</a>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>">Next</a><br/>

<?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?><br/>

<?php 
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>";
else echo "<a href='#' style='float:left; margin:0px 5px;'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a>";
if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Thank to all of you, for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use elseif($day === number) like so:

```
<?php

$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");

$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];

$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;

if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
$prev_month = 12;
$prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}

if ($next_month == 13 ) {
$next_month = 1;
$next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>">Previous</a>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>">Next</a><br/>

<?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?><br/>

<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";

    $day = $i - $startday + 1;

    if($i < $startday) {
        echo "<td></td>";
    } elseif( $day === 14) {
        echo "<a href='http://google.com/' style='float:left; margin:0px 5px;'>". $day . "</a>";
    }
    elseif( $day === 20) {
        echo "<a href='http://yahoo.com/' style='float:left; margin:0px 5px;'>". $day . "</a>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<a href='#' style='float:left; margin:0px 5px;'>". $day . "</a>";
    }
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but i am getting theese errors: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) on line 49; and same with elseif :/

Comment: forgot the opening bracket, sry. i just edited the post, please try again :)

Comment: Already done that! Thank you again and good luck with other codes! <3

Comment: One more question: how about months? Because, if i am clicking "Next" month button, than 14th and 20th is also active. How i can disable this function if month is different? :/

Comment: You would add a condition check for the month to the elseif(). Something like `elseif( ($day === 14) && ($cMonth === 3) )` or exclude with `elseif( ($day === 14) && ($cMonth !== 5) )` .. instead of $cMonth, it might be $thismonth. give it a try..

Comment: Hmm, first method dont work. It gives no errors, but it disables hyperlink in all months. Second and third methods works as same as your accepted answer. Nothing changes :/ what do you think about that? I know that this code ir pretty shity, but i dont have alternatives :/